# Maven can't found a jar from my local repository

Tags: java, maven

This is my setting.xml for `localRepository`

`<localRepository>D:/dev/tools/apache-maven-3.3.9/repo</localRepository>`

This is jar in my local repository
[This is jar in my local repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZILxR.png)

When run 'mvn tomcat6:run'
[Run 'mvn tomcat6:run'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfnnA.png)

I wonder why the Maven need to download 'gdata-client-1.0.jar' from remote repository again.

If you can understand what I mean, and you know the answer, please tell me. Thx!

Comment: try maven `clean install`

Comment: First local repository into Maven installation is not a good idea. Better leave the default which is $HOME/.m2/repository. Apart from that copy&past text and don't insert images...

Answer (score 0):

*.lastUpdated files indicate that Maven tried to obtain the archive by downloading, but was unsuccessful. they are not actual files

Comment: But 'commons-lang.jar’ have same problem.

local folder is

_commons-lang-2.6.jar_
_commons-lang-2.6.jar.sha1_
_commons-lang-2.6.pom_
_commons-lang-2.6.pom.sha1_

Comment: If you see jars with out lastUpdated, like gdata-client-1.0.jar, this means jar is downloaded.  You can also build offline using -o option.